# Kalman Filtering and Smoothing - the effect of adding a new set of observed values to latent state

Tags: time-series, kalman-filter

For such a latent space model
$$z_t = A z_{t-1} + w_t$$
$$x_t = C z_t + v_t$$
where the noise is being drawn $w_t \sim N(0, Q)$ and $v_t \sim N(0, R)$
I have the derivation of the forward and backward pass equations for $\mu_{t|t}$, $\Sigma_{t|t}$, $\mu_{t|t+1}$ and $\Sigma_{t|t+1}$.
Now add a new set of **observed** variables {$y_t$} so that the model becomes
$$z_t = A z_{t-1} + B y_t + w_t$$
$$x_t = C z_t + v_t$$
How would this $y_t$ change the filtering and smoothing steps?